# Resources to learn QT/Embedded 4.5?

Tags: linux, qt, embedded-linux

Can you please give me Resources(Books, Tutorials, Other useful links ) to learn QT/Embedded 4.5, To get quick start in QT programming.

P.S. I am quite familiar with windoing system programming and C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a look at the official help: http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qt-embedded.html. Then Qt on embedded platform is the same as on other platform. So "standard" help is great: http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/index.html.

Answer (score 3):

BOOK

IMHO the best beginners' book is Foundations of Qt Development by Johan Thelin.

http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590598318

(see also google books for a good preview)

The first 4 chapters (120 pages) are a great hands-on introduction to all you need to know to start developing applications in Qt.

The following 12 chapters go in detail into specific topics (eg files and xml, databases, threading, networking, project building, drawing and printing, ...).

CODE EXAMPLES

Once you read the first 4 chapters, you'll be able to easily navigate Qt's excellent documentation.

At that point you can dive into the examples Qt provides (on Mac OS X they get installed in /Developer/Examples/Qt). There are many, so you're bound to find something relevant. All are of high quality, and some have a walk-through documentation.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

For starting Qt Programming there is an excellent book you should download immediately.  It is titled "C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4, Second Edition".  Go Google it up and find a copy in either PDF or CHM format.  Yes, it is perfectly legal.

Search up this term and you should be able to find it:
"GUI Programming With Qt 4 2nd Edition.chm"

or change the file type to PDF.  It's out there.  My understanding is that it is a perfectly legal download, but I never bookmarked when I obtained it.

http://qt.nokia.com/developer/books

has a listing of good books you can purchase.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page and hunt up the book download:

http://dcsoft.com/community_server/blogs/dcsoft/archive/2009/03/24/book-review-c-gui-programming-with-qt-4-second-edition-by-jasmin-blanchette-and-mark-summerfield-prentice-hall.aspx

Comment: Link is broken.